# Environment variables in prometheus values

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

i would like to set environment specific values based on environment qa/prod in prometheus values file

```
 ## Additional alertmanager container environment variable
  ## For instance to add a http_proxy
  ##
  extraEnv: {}
```

Answer (score 7):

Prometheus does not support environment variables. There are a [few threads discussing this](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2357) in GitHub.

You can use envsubs or if you want a more robust and versatile tool I recommend to GO with Confd (its written in GO :D). You can also get the secrets from backends like etcd or AWS ssm.

[Here](https://github.com/zakkg3/Prometheus-confd) you have Pormetheus with confd ready to go (just need to modify the config to your needs.

Comment: lol @ GO dad pun, levels to this

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus doesn't support environment variables in config file. But other Prometheus-like systems such as VictoriaMetrics support env vars in Prometheus-compatible config files via `%{ENV_VAR}` syntax. For example, the following config would substitute `%{ENV}` with `qa` or `prod` if the corresponding `ENV=qa` or `ENV=prod` environment variable is passed to [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) or [vmagent](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html):

```yaml
scrape_configs:
- job_name: foo
  static_configs:
  - targets: [foobar:1234]
    labels:
      env: '%{ENV}'
```

This allows using the same Prometheus config in different environments and templating it with environment variables. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-scrape-prometheus-exporters-such-as-node-exporter) for details.